# Java program works in Windows but not in Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos

Hi I have done a program that send a screen capture over a socket. Well, it works if I take the screen capture in the mac and send it to the windows pc(7, xp doest work), but if i want to take the screen capture in windows and send it to the mac it just send part of the file... Here is the client

```
public class Enviar {

private static int port = 3460; /* port to connect to */
private static String host = "192.168.1.135"; /* host to connect to */





private BufferedReader in = null;
private static PrintWriter outr = null;
private static Socket server;
private static OutputStream outFile;
private static InputStream inFile;

 public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Socket server = null;
        InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        while (true) {
        try {
            server = new Socket(ina, port);
            if (server != null) { 
                break; 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            //System.exit(1);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        }





        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
        outFile = server.getOutputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));





    inFile = server.getInputStream();
    outr = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
    outr.flush();
    String msg;





    while (true){
    try {

        while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(msg + "2");
            if (msg.equals("screen")) {
                 outr.println("screenon");
                 outr.flush();
                 try
                 {
                server();

                 }  

                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
    }
    }

 static void server() throws Exception {
    captureScreen("screencapture.png");

         InputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("screencapture.png");



         copy(inFile, outFile);

         inFile.close();

         System.out.println("Mandado");
    }


    static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }

    static public void captureScreen(String fileName) throws Exception {
        String OSz = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if (OSz.equals("Mac OS X")) {

            System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "True");
        }
    Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
    }
```

}

And The server

```
public class Recibir {
    private  static Socket client;
    private static BufferedReader in ;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static OutputStream outFile;
    private static InputStream inFile;
    static int port = 3460;
    static ServerSocket server;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        server.setSoTimeout(1000);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port:" + port);
    } 
    System.out.println("bitch2");
    while (true){   
    try {

        client = server.accept();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        inFile = client.getInputStream();

        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        String msg;

        out.println("screen");
        if ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (msg.equals("screenon")){

            client();
            }
         }


            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
    }



    }
static void client() throws IOException {
    OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("copied.png",false);
    copyScreen(inFile, outFile);
    outFile.close();

    //inFile.close();
    System.out.println("Guardado");

}

static void copyScreen(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0, counter = 0;


    while (bytesRead >= 0) {
        bytesRead = in.read(buf);
        if (bytesRead >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            counter += bytesRead;
            System.out.println("total bytes read: " +
                                            counter);
        }
        if (bytesRead < 1024) {
            out.flush();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.println("bitch2");` I, too, debug aggressively.

Comment: @Kon Haha, until you submit that code and it turns up in a code review.

Comment: @KevinBowersox even better. Office power play! Just make direct eye contact with the code reviewer the entire time. Don't laugh. Best. day. ever.